# Wigner-Eckart theorem for exponentiated vector operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, representation-theory, wigner-eckart

Consider the Hamiltonian of two spinning particles in a magnetic field with $$H = \vec{B}\cdot\vec{\mu}$$ where $$\vec{\mu} = \alpha \vec{L}_1+\beta\vec{L}_2$$
Now I wish to compute its partition function given by
$$Z = \text{Tr}(e^{-\beta H})$$ Since, the trace would involve tracing over states $|\alpha, jm\rangle$, so eventually I would have to consider the matrix element of the form $$\langle\alpha', j m'|e^{-\beta H}|\alpha, j m\rangle$$
I can certianly compute this in a weak magnetic field and use the projection theorem to compute $Z$ but I wish to know if there is a clever way to get this done for a magnetic field of arbitrary strength. Is there an exponentiated version of the Wigner-Eckart theorem?